# Laravel Vite assets from https

Tags: laravel, https, vite

Vite on production is taking assets from `http` despite APP_URL is set to `https://`.

[image]

How to resolve this in the Vite config? I can't change Laravel AppServiceProvider to force to use https because this would cause other issues.

I use `@vite` directive to get resources, I can change that if needed:

```
@vite('resources/js/app.js')
```

I tried `vite build -- --https` but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73983476/laravel-9-vite-how-to-use-https-assets-using-vite)?

Comment: also, clear config cache .

Comment: @franciso - this is using AppServiceProvider - I can't do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding `ASSET_URL` (with https) fixed the issue. It wasn't set at all in `.env` and Vite decided to pull through `http://`.